# Overriding admin view methods - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

**I need to override the an add form within the admin panel.**

**I'm thinking of accomplishing this by writing a view which would then point to the admin view for the final result.**

Something similar to this (where admin_basic_ass_user_view is the admin view)

```
@required_login
def add_user(request):
    if condition:
        return admin_basic_add_user_view(request)
    return render_to_response("admin/auth/user/add_form.html", { ... })
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to override the logic or just the template?

Comment: @stefanw: the logic, e.g. password validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just override the relevant methods with your ModelAdmin subclass? That's why it's a class, after all.

Comment: basically what you are saying is to subclass the User ModelAdmin and implement the changes in there? but then how do I cleanly replace the old admin interface with the new one?

Comment: How to override admin templates: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: I wish I could add advanced password validation by overriding a template, thanks btw

Comment: @RadiantHex to replace the existing user admin just do `admin.site.unregister(User)`, then `admin.site.register(User, MyNewUserAdmin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this to your urls.py

```
((r'^admin/auth/users/add/$', 'Project.SomeAPP.admin_views.add_user'),
```

The path needs to point to your new view. You should see the results of your new view in the admin interface's add user page.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, make sure you add that line BEFORE the normal admin interface line in the urls.py